# Kohler set screw for shower handle

Tags: shower

Does anybody know how to put this (https://www.us.kohler.com/us//productDetail/screw/626005.htm?skuId=589148) set screw into a Stillness Kohler shower handle (https://www.us.kohler.com/us/stillness-rite-temp-valve-trim-with-lever-handle/productDetail/handle-trim/1270658.htm?skuId=1270570&brandId=empty&)?  I can't figure out the right hex key to make it work. It seems like a 2.5mm is too big, and a 2mm is too small. Do they make 2.25mm hex keys? Or is it perhaps a proprietary Kohler tool that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction sheet you provided says you need a 3/32" allen wrench.

Comment: Both you and @ACK responded within similar time. I’ll look for 3/32. Is that a standard size in an Allen wrench set?

Comment: It is in my small set but not in my larger set. Most home stores will sell them individually.  Bring the set screw with you.... AND DON'T LOOSE IT.

Comment: sounds great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably SAE and not metric. Try 3/32"